# Ubuntu 22.04.3, Kernel 6.5.0-XX-generic and RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

Tags: drivers, 22.04

This morning 2 of my Ubuntu installs that are both `22.04.3 LTS` running HWE upgraded to Kernel `6.5.0-14-generic`.  After rebooting both systems the network cards that are `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller` did not come up.  Booting to the older 6.2.0-39-generic Kernel the network card works just fine.  Upon trying to reinstall the `r8168-dkms` driver which installs the driver version `8.049.02` fails.  And running `sudo lshw -C network` is showing the card as `UNCLAIMED`.

The issue is the `r8168-dkms` driver that is in the default repos is running version `8.049.02-1ubuntu1` that is incompatible with the`6.5.0-14-generic` Kernel.

```
$ apt-cache policy r8168-dkms
r8168-dkms:
  Installed: 8.049.02-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 8.049.02-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 8.049.02-1ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.049.02-1ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
     8.049.02-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
```

And when you try to build the `8.049.02` driver in the `6.5.0-14-generic` Kernel you get the following error message:

```
$ sudo dkms build r8168/8.049.02
Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-14-generic -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build..........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for r8168: 8.049.02 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/make.log for more information.

$ cat /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/make.log
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:27733:24: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘skb_gso_reset’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
27733 |                 segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, features);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        skb_gso_reset
```

Even if you change the source code to match the `did you mean...` it will still fail.  But, the `8.049.02` driver builds just fine in the older `6.2` and `5.15` kernels.

Is there a more up to date driver that I can use?

*P.S.  I will not use the `r8169` driver for my `r8168` chipset as it will work OK in the beginning but after a little bit will give unpredictable behavior, some to the point of needing a hard reboot of my system to bring the interface back up.*

Comment: I had a USB to ethernet adapter. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: I have a similar problem using Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.5, it lost the network adapter. The only way to make things work is to reboot and select kernel 6.2 in the grub.

Comment: @JonathanMartins Yep, I did write that into my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE:** I had noticed that if I had booted into Windows 10 that when I booted back to Ubuntu without a hard power cycle that the NIC would not work correctly.  This was actually due to the driver version in Windows creating this problem for some reason.  To fix it I had booted back into Windows and downloaded and installed the `10.69` driver from [Realtek](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) themselves.  Now rebooting from Windows back into Ubuntu there is no issues.

---

**Driver Installation:**

*I would file a bug on `r8168-dkms` but it is stating that it is not an official package.*

The `8.049.02` version or `r8168-dkms` driver that is currently in the repos for 22.04 LTS appears to be incompatible with the `6.5.0-14-generic` Kernel and `dkms` cannot install the driver.

Boot back to a working Kernel and download the Realtek `8.052.01` driver from [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software).

*p.s. The `autorun.sh` file does not setup the driver in `dkms` which would require you to reinstall the driver on the next Kernel update.*

Before installing the new driver, I recommend removing the `8.049.02` driver from the tree so that `dkms` does not try to install it into newer Kernels that it will fail in.

```
sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all
```

After downloading the driver, go ahead and extract the files.

```
tar xvf r8168-8.052.01.tar.bz2
```

Enter the new directory that was created.

```
cd r8168-8.052.01/src
```

Create a new Kernel source directory for the driver.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01
```

And copy all the files to the new directory.

```
sudo cp -v * /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01/
```

Create a new `dkms.conf` file for the driver.

```
sudo nano /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01/dkms.conf
```

and now add the following content to the file.

```
PACKAGE_NAME="r8168"
PACKAGE_VERSION="8.052.01"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="$PACKAGE_NAME"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
REMAKE_INITRD="YES"
```

Save the file and run the next lines to build and install the driver.

```
sudo dkms add r8168/8.052.01
sudo dkms build r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.5.0-14-generic
sudo dkms install r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.5.0-14-generic
```

*Make sure to change the Kernel version (6.5.0-XX-generic) on the 2 lines above to match your current Kernel you are trying to install into.*

Now when you check the `dkms status` you should see the new driver installed into the kernel.

```
$ dkms status
r8168/8.052.01, 5.15.0-91-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.052.01, 6.2.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-14-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Reboot the system and boot into the newest Kernel and the RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller should come up fine.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this solved my problem! I'm running with kernel 6.5 after following this steps!

Comment: Everything worked fine with `6.5.0-14-generic` until I apt upgraded my system. Same problem came up with `6.5.0-15-generic`. The system says that the driver is installed but the nic does not work. `dkms status` shows `r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed`. Running the `autorun.sh` shows me this `warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel`, the kernel was built by: `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12`, you are using: `gcc-12`, but it completes without errors and without solving the problem. Rebooting into 6.2 solves the problem temporarily!

Comment: @JonathanMartins That compiler difference is just a warning.  Running the `autorun.sh` might destroy the `dkms` install.  I don't recommend it.  You might just need to boot back into the 6.5.0-15-generic kernel, do a `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.052.01` and then do a reinstall as `sudo dkms install r8168/8.052.01 --force`, reboot again.  I don't know why yours failed, as when I got the 6.5.0-15-generic it worked fine, rebooted after install and NIC came right back up without any problems.  You're not dual booting with Windows are you?

Comment: Yes, I have dual boot with windows. The problem was solved after reinstalling everything. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Same problem happened when upgrading to `6.5.0-17-generic`. This time nothing here could help me. Nothing that I did could solved the problem. At the end I give up and did the only thing that I could not believe that should solved the problem! I reboot to windows and installed the indicated realtek driver: `10.69`. After a simple reboot back to ubuntu, everything worked fine! Crazy shit!

Comment: @JonathanMartins I agree!  It puzzled me that updating the Windows driver to 10.69 fixed the issues I was having with Ubuntu.  Go figure!  Glad it helped you too!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if r8169, which is builtin in kernel, works well now with your controller. Purging `r8168-dkms` worked for me

Comment: I will not use the r8169 driver on my r8168 chipset.  Over the years it has made me need to hard reset my system as a simple reboot and the NIC won't come back up.  On my server with an actual r8169 and a r8168 card they conflict and my 8168 will just go offline.  I have found the r8169 driver to be garbage on the r8168 chipset.

Answer (score 0):

Download version 8.052.01 from [drivers](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software)

execute `sudo autorun.sh`

No **restart** need

Comment: The downside to this installation is that it does not install the driver into dkms which would require a reinstallation on the next Kernel update.