# removing dkms r8168 from dkms three

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

my problem was my network adapter doesn't come up when running on newer kernel : 6.5.0-15-generic. the problem was solved using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499659/ubuntu-22-04-3-kernel-6-5-0-14-generic-and-rtl8111-8168-8411-pci-express-gigabi?newreg=efb9c9f348ea415b913812000165379e).

my next problem is, every time i run an update, it keep doing this

```
Removing old r8168-8.049.02 DKMS files...
Deleting module r8168-8.049.02 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new r8168-8.049.02 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-15-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-15-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/r8168-dkms.0.cr
ash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package r8168-dkms (--configure):
 installed r8168-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 10
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic
Ada kesalahan saat memproses: 
 r8168-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

it doesn't ruin my system by the way, but i kind of scared me, that it may does sometime later

is there anyway i can fix this?

**PS : sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is that dkms is trying to rebuild the `8.049.02` driver into the `6.5.0-15-generic` kernel.  You can remove the driver completely.

First run `dkms status` to list the installed versions:

```
$ dkms status
r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-14-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Then to remove the driver just run the following:

```
sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 -k 6.2.0-39-generic
```

Make sure that after the `-k` you put in your kernel version that the `8.049.02` driver is installed into.

You can add the `8.052.01` driver into the Kernel you also just removed the driver from.

```
sudo dkms install r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.2.0-39-generic --force
```

Comment: what happen if i boot back into my 6.5.0-14 generic kernel, doesnt it couse any system error? especialy on my network adapter

Comment: @dontknowanything You can run the `dkms status` and if you see the `8.052.01` driver installed in the `6.5.0-14-generic` Kernel you will be fine booting back into that Kernel then and have the network still work.  The `8.049.02` driver is NOT compatible at all with the `6.5.0-XX-generic` Kernel.

Comment: my dkms status resulting : 
r8168/8.049.02: added
r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: @dontknowanything run `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all` to get rid of it.  You should be good in the 6.5.0-15-generic

Comment: `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all`

and the error message still came up

Comment: @dontknowanything Are you saying that `dkms status` is still listing the `r8168/8.049.02` driver as being added?

Comment: after run `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all` and then `dkms status` it show only `r8168/8.052.01, 6.5.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed`

but if i run an udpate && upgrade
the error messages show again, as if the dkms for r8168/8.049.02, 6.2.0-39-generic still there

Comment: @dontknowanything What happens if you run `sudo apt autoremove r8168-dkms`?  I would make sure that you still have the directory of when you downloaded the `r8168-8.052.01` driver as running the apt command might uninstall the newest driver as well.  As if it uninstalls it, you will need to reinstall the newest driver again.

Comment: i kind of away from my PC, i let you know as soon as i get there

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  r8168-dkms
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1.377 kB disk space will be freed.
Removing r8168-dkms (8.049.02-1ubuntu1.2) ...
Deleting module r8168-8.049.02 completely from the DKMS tree.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-17-generic`

Comment: recently i install an update for newest kernel i guest, version 6.5.0-17 generic
still got the same error on dkms module, but after that i running apt auto remove above, and then update && upgrade again, the problem was gone, i think "maybe" the newest kernel fix it. but thanks too captain