# Realtek 8168 chip driver fails to compile a valid driver on kernel 6.5.0-15-generic

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, realtek

I am trying to install the Realtek official drivers because the r8168-dkms fails to work well.

Log:

```
cat /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for r8168-8.049.02 for kernel 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Tue Feb  6 09:10:19 AM AST 2024
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_asf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtl_eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/rtltool.o
In file included from ./include/linux/string.h:254,
                 from ./include/linux/bitmap.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/cpumask.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:17,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpuid.h:62,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:19,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/timex.h:67,
                 from ./include/linux/time32.h:13,
                 from ./include/linux/time.h:60,
                 from ./include/linux/stat.h:19,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:13,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:43:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_set_mac_address’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24197:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__builtin_memcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
24197 |         memcpy(dev->dev_addr, addr->sa_data, dev->addr_len);
      |                ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:648:27: note: in definition of macro ‘__fortify_memcpy_chk’
  648 |         __underlying_##op(p, q, __fortify_size);                        \
      |                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24197:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘memcpy’
24197 |         memcpy(dev->dev_addr, addr->sa_data, dev->addr_len);
      |         ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24197:19: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’
24197 |         memcpy(dev->dev_addr, addr->sa_data, dev->addr_len);
      |                ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/fortify-string.h:648:27: note: in definition of macro ‘__fortify_memcpy_chk’
  648 |         __underlying_##op(p, q, __fortify_size);                        \
      |                           ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24197:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘memcpy’
24197 |         memcpy(dev->dev_addr, addr->sa_data, dev->addr_len);
      |         ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24199:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘rtl8168_rar_set’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
24199 |         rtl8168_rar_set(tp, dev->dev_addr);
      |                             ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:575:59: note: expected ‘uint8_t *’ {aka ‘unsigned char *’} but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’
  575 | void rtl8168_rar_set(struct rtl8168_private *tp, uint8_t *addr);
      |                                                  ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘r8168_csum_workaround’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:27733:24: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘skb_gso_reset’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
27733 |                 segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, features);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        skb_gso_reset
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:27733:22: warning: assignment to ‘struct sk_buff *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
27733 |                 segs = skb_gso_segment(skb, features);
      |                      ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_resume’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:28693:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘rtl8168_rar_set’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
28693 |         rtl8168_rar_set(tp, dev->dev_addr);
      |                             ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.c:24214:26: note: expected ‘uint8_t *’ {aka ‘unsigned char *’} but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’
24214 |                 uint8_t *addr)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic/Makefile:2037: /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.049.02/build] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-15-generic'
```

```
lspci | grep Ethernet
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

I also tried to add the code myself but I made a mistake to do for 6.5.0-14. Also deleted `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/` and `asudo rm -rf /var/lib/dkms/r8168/` and seems like something is lingering and not letting me retry the steps.

Console output:

```
sudo dkms build r8168/8.052.01 --force
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-15-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/make.log for more information.
cat /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for r8168-8.052.01 for kernel 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Tue Feb  6 10:45:03 AM AST 2024
make -C src/ clean
make -C src/ modules
make -C src/ install
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.052.01/build/src'
make: *** [Makefile:48: clean] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:41: modules] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:55: install] Error 2
```

```
sudo dkms build r8168 -v 8.052.01 -k 6.5.0-15-generic --force //Can't force rebuild since Makefile has no clean rule.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j12 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-15-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic (x86_64)

NOTE: I had noticed that if I had booted into Windows 10 that when I booted back to Ubuntu without a hard power cycle that the NIC would not work correctly. This was actually due to the driver version in Windows creating this problem for some reason. To fix it I had booted back into Windows and downloaded and installed the 10.69 driver from Realtek themselves. Now rebooting from Windows back into Ubuntu there is no issues.
```

**Driver Installation:**

I would file a bug on r8168-dkms but it is stating that it is not an official package.

The 8.049.02 version or r8168-dkms driver that is currently in the repos for 22.04 LTS appears to be incompatible with the 6.5.0-14-generic Kernel and dkms cannot install the driver.

Boot back to a working Kernel and download the Realtek 8.052.01 driver from here.

p.s. The autorun.sh file does not setup the driver in dkms which would require you to reinstall the driver on the next Kernel update.

Before installing the new driver, I recommend removing the 8.049.02 driver from the tree so that dkms does not try to install it into newer Kernels that it will fail in.

```
sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all
```

After downloading the driver, go ahead and extract the files.

```
tar xvf r8168-8.052.01.tar.bz2
```

Enter the new directory that was created.

```
cd r8168-8.052.01/src
```

Create a new Kernel source directory for the driver.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01
```

And copy all the files to the new directory.

```
sudo cp -v * /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01/
```

Create a new dkms.conf file for the driver.

```
sudo nano /usr/src/r8168-8.052.01/dkms.conf
```

and now add the following content to the file.

```
PACKAGE_NAME="r8168"
PACKAGE_VERSION="8.052.01"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="$PACKAGE_NAME"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
AUTOINSTALL="YES"
REMAKE_INITRD="YES"
```

Save the file and run the next lines to build and install the driver.

```
sudo dkms add r8168/8.052.01
sudo dkms build r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.5.0-14-generic
sudo dkms install r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.5.0-14-generic
```

[SOURCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499659/ubuntu-22-04-3-kernel-6-5-0-14-generic-and-rtl8111-8168-8411-pci-express-gigabi)

Answer (score 1):

According to your log you have remnants of the 8.049.02 driver left over. That driver version is not compatible with the 6.5.0-xx-generic Kernel. Best to remove it.  Your new driver should be installed already, but if you don't want to see it any more, remove the driver.

```
sudo dkms remove r8168/8.049.02 --all
```

and that should remove it completely from Kernel tree.

Whatever Kernel version the old driver gets removed from you can add the new driver back into.  i.e. r8168/8.049.02 gets removed from 6.2.0-39-generic, you would then run the following to add it back into that Kernel.

```
sudo dkms build r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.2.0-39-generic
sudo dkms install r8168/8.052.01 -k 6.2.0-39-generic
```

You can always view which drivers are installed by running `dkms status`.

Comment: Yeah. I did remove it so far. stuck at the new info i added: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Bgg4sDKDK3/ The LOG is from the r816-dkms package

Comment: @binarydepth84 I have to run to a dentist appointment then work, but you can try copying and pasting a new script I wrote that can help in removing and reinstalling the driver:  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/QXcDXXDrps/

Comment: @binarydepth84 I also think from the original install you might have missed going into the full directory of 'r8168-8.052.01/src/' before copying the files to the new Kernel directory.  The script I gave you above though takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I think the issue is with DKMS. I can try your script again an make a bin of the log when it fails

Comment: I finally got it to compile and add but now it doesn't get used, meaning I have to modprobe at login. I got another script - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vmPZy88b2g/

@Terrance

Comment: I am going to have to report this to Realtek