Why can't I set link speed above 10Mb/s (with ethtool)
I installed a cat6 cable to connect to my router (I assembled the RJ45 connectors by myself, and tested it using a RJ45 tester). The connection works, but at 10Mb/s only :
sudo lshw -C network
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   produit: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   fabricant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   identifiant matériel: 0
   information bus: pci@0000:04:00.0
   nom logique: enp4s0
   version: 10
   numéro de série: a0:8c:fd:28:fc:7b
   taille: 10Mbit/s
   capacité: 1Gbit/s
   bits: 64 bits
   horloge: 33MHz
   fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-117-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
   ressources : irq:16 portE/S:d000(taille=256) mémoire:df004000-df004fff mémoire:df000000-df003fff

Using the hints provided in that discussion, I tried to increase the speed with:
sudo ethtool -s enp4s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off

However, this just disable the connection. This is also true with speed 100Mb/s. I can set autoneg to off if I keep a speed of 10Mb/s.
The router interface doesn't provide an option for applying similar settings on the router side.
I am wondering whether there is an issue with the physical layers (I mean, the connectors I installed on the cable, or the quite long length of that cable : ~38m), or if I should dig further on how to change router settings

The 8169 driver running on the 8168 chipset can cause some strange behavior.
Install the 8168 driver on your system and it should help in correcting issues you may be experiencing.
I would recommend following through this other answer I have written because the driver that is part of the r8168-dkms package does not work with the 6.5.XX kernel.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1499660/231142
Hope this helps!

Thanks for the suggestion. Because I have a 5.15.xx kernel, I assumed I can simply install the r8168-dkms package, which I did. This however didn't solve the problem : setting speed to 100 Mb/s just disable the link. Setting it to 1000 Mb/s causes error messages in addition netlink error: link settings update failed netlink error: Invalid argument

By the way  How can I check that I know use the 8168 driver ? (the output of sudo lshw -C network did not change, it still shows RTL8111/8168/8411)

@Stéphane Run sudo lshw -C network | grep driver from the terminal and it should show you something like configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.053.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s as you should see driver=r8168.  In your question above you show driver=r8169.

Thanks. The driver now definitely is r8168. So the hint doesn't work for my case.

@Stéphane Have you tried another operating system to make sure that it isn't the OS causing the issue?  Have you tried connecting your system to another network to make sure that it isn't your hardware?  I hate to say it, but there is a possibility of a miswire as well.  There is also the possibility of a bad network connector on the system.

Actually, the issue was with the physical layer : my RJ45 connectors were quite difficult to wire correctly (at least with the tool I have).
Interesting to notice is that the connection test tool I used didn't report any problem, which was misleading
Thanks a lot
