Ethernet not working on ubuntu (RealtekRTL8111/8168/8411), Works fine on windows
I have an issue with my Ethernet connection on Ubuntu 22.04. I have a dual boot system with Windows 11, and the Ethernet connection works fine on Windows (the port LED lights up, and I get a stable connection). However, when I switch to Ubuntu, the Ethernet connection doesn’t work, and the LED on the Ethernet port doesn’t light up at all.
Here’s some info about my system and what I’ve tried so far:
Network card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Ubuntu version: 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish
What I’ve tried:
I ran lshw -C network and the Ethernet interface (enp4s0) is listed.
Tried restarting NetworkManager with sudo service NetworkManager restart.
Unfortunately, I can’t use apt or install new drivers directly as I don’t have internet access on Ubuntu.
I’m wondering if I need to manually install a driver for the Realtek Ethernet card. If so, could someone guide me on how to install it without an internet connection, or suggest any other possible solutions?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Some information from https://askubuntu.com/a/1499660 helped me solve this. Here are the steps I followed:

Boot into Windows
Go to https://www.realtek.com/Download/List?cate_id=584
In the Windows section, download version 10.73 and install it
Boot into Linux
Go to https://www.realtek.com/Download/List?cate_id=584
In the Unix (Linux) section, download version 8.054.00 (GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8168 for kernel up to 6.8)
Run these commands:

    sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) dkms
    
    tar xvf r8168-8.054.00.tar.bz2

    cd r8168-8.054.00/src

    sudo mkdir /usr/src/r8168-8.054.00

    sudo cp -v * /usr/src/r8168-8.054.00/
    
    sudo tee <<EOF /usr/src/r8168-8.054.00/dkms.conf >/dev/null

    PACKAGE_NAME="r8168"
    PACKAGE_VERSION="8.054.00"
    BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="$PACKAGE_NAME"
    DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
    AUTOINSTALL="YES"
    REMAKE_INITRD="YES"

    EOF
    
    sudo dkms add r8168/8.054.00
    
    sudo dkms build r8168/8.054.00 -k $(uname -r)
    
    sudo dkms install r8168/8.054.00 -k $(uname -r)


Running "dkms status" should now show the Ethernet chipset
Reboot

